# Qt/C++ Memory leaking signal slot

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks

I am using signal slots with custom defined object. A thirdparty library is used to retrieve some measurements and the result is shared with different threads.

```
struct Measurement_t{
    uint temp
};

void onMeasure(){
 Measurement_t meas = Measurement_t();
 if(::do_measuring(&meas)){
    emit sigDataMeasured(meas);
 }
}

signal definition:
void sigDataMeasured(Measurement_t meas);
```

I have this signal connected to three different threads. The thing is using top I can see that the thread where the measuring happens is leaking memory. The only operation I do in this thread on a regular basis is the measuring, therefore I suspect this to be the issue. When I wrote this method I thought that the slots connected to my signal (QueuedConnection) only receive a copy and the instance meas is cleaned as soon as the method is left?

Is this correct?

Comment: AFAIK this is correct reasoning, it doesn't seem this thread leaks memory

Comment: How do you see, that you are leaking memory?

Comment: Which operating system, which compiler? I recommend to use address sanitizer available in clang and gcc to detect and localize actual memory leaks.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX by using top pressing <ctrl+h> to get a list of the threads. I can see that the virtual memory used by my thread is climbing continously

Comment: only thing I could imagine is, that you allocate memory and don't release it in the `do_measuring`function

Comment: It could be because of the Qt memory handling semantics. Do you new anything? Some Widgets? How did your connect the slots exactly? Do you use Qt containers? Look into `deleteLater` and copy on write in Qt Containers on how screwed up Qt Widget Lifetime Management is.

Comment: @Superlokkus I don't see how widgets (the thread in question is a non-UI thread) or CoW (that's implicit to the container and doesn't leak) should affect the behavior here.

Comment: You should do some valgrind profiling for your program to see if there is some 'real memory leak'. For performance, Qt uses cache memory for alot of things, meaning that lots of memory are not released to system after used.

Comment: Another option is that you're posting messages to objects whose thread is not running or whose event loop is not dequeuing messages. That will cause a pile-up.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I meant any QObject based instance of anything, which is often misused for life time management.